# A single word meaning "Monetary Anti-Counterfeiting Measures?"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I saw it once long ago in a book on money, but cannot remember it and have never found it online.

Comment: **Anti-Counterfeiting-Measures** works.

Comment: "Watermark" is the only obvious single word I can think of.

Comment: True, but in a broader context. The word I seek is very specific to numismatics. It's not a word with broader application. It's an unusual word, not one I'd ever run across before.

Answer (score 3):

*[authentication](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/authentication)*:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1 The process or action of proving or showing something to
>   be true, genuine, or valid:
>   *the prints will be stamped with his seal and accompanied by a letter of authentication*
>
> [AS COUNT NOUN]:
>   *the authentications were both carried out by the Investigation Bureau of
>   the Ministry of Justice*

Comment: Thanks, but no. It is a specific term with no other applications. An unusual word I had never heard before and haven't since. It is narrowly concerned with only monetary authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to indicate the measures that are aimed to stop counterfeiters, *security features* is the term you are looking for.

It is stretching a bit but possibly *hallmark* fits the bill.

Comment: That's a good phrase, but it encompasses more than anti-counterfeiting technology. I'm seeking a specific, single word. It exists, I just can't recall it.

Comment: Maybe this reference helps: http://www.moneyfactory.gov/anticounterfeiting/securityfeatures.html

Comment: Ha! I actually read that site yesterday, which brought the current question back to mind. A good read, but it doesn't have my word.

Comment: Duh. And verification mark is two words as well...It is now stuck in my mind as well. Be assured I'll post in case it pops up later...